# Point to the function created in C# project from generic typename in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

C++/CLI :

```
public interface class ITest{
    public:
          virtual void doSomething (){
           }
}

public ref Base {
      ...........
      ...........
}

generic <typename T> where T : ITest
public ref Derived : Base{
    public:
          virtual void doNothing (){
           }
}

public ref AnotherClass {
public:
        generic<class T> where T : Base
    static int justDoThis(){
                //Problem!!
        }
}
```

C# :

In C# there are two classes `A` and `B`. `A` inherits from the `ITest` and `B` inherits from `Derived` where `A` is used as the typename. Also, `B` has a private variable of type `A`. So, from main function `AnotherClass.justDoThis<B>()` is called where `B` is passed as the generic type.

"//Problem!!" Part :

Now I have to create a new instance of `B` in this section and also access the `A` which is private variable in `B`.

Answer (score 1):

So if I take your paragraph of description of the C# code:

```
class A : ITest {}

class B : Derived<A>
{
    private A someVariableOfTypeA;
}

class Program
{
    void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AnotherClass.justDoThis<B>();
    }
}
```

And the problem is that you want to do this:

```
public ref AnotherClass {
public:
    generic<class T> where T : Base
    static int justDoThis()
    {
        // Problem!!
        Something^ actuallyB = gcnew Something();
        A^ a = actuallyB->someVariableOfTypeA;
    }
}
```

Issue #1: You can allow creation of new objects of the generic type by specifying `gcnew` as another generic constraint. (In C#, this would be `new`.) This will require that the generic type have a default (i.e., parameterless) constructor, which you can access with the normal `gcnew`.

```
generic<class T> where T : Base, gcnew
static int justDoThis()
{
    T^ t = gcnew T();
}
```

Issue #2: You cannot access private variables within an object. That's what private means. If you want to give `justDoThis` access to the `A` object, then add an appropriate public method or property to `Base`. The method or property would return type `ITest`. You could also put that method/property on a new interface (perhaps named `IHaveAnITestAccessorMethod`), and add that as another generic constraint, and `B` satisfies all the constraints.

Note that it won't do any good to make the variable public on type `B`: `justDoThis` doesn't know about `B`, it only knows about `T`, which is a `Base` with a no parameter constructor.

<sub>Disclaimers:</sub>

- <sub>I didn't check my syntax with a compiler.</sub>
- <sub>Yes, you can do anything with reflection, but that's a bad design. Don't do that, fix your code the right way.</sub>

Comment: Hello Yaw, I am new to C++/CLI. Thank you for your reply but the issue 1 is not possible. As error shows while building: cannot use gcnew to allocate a generic type. I am using safe_cast <TService>(System::Activator::CreateInstance (TService::typeid)). I now want to do 2 things. First pass this istance to another generic function with no where clause. Second, inside that another function I want to use the the override functionality which is written in A from ITest

Comment: What is `TService`? You don't have a `TService` in your question. Also, please ask one question per post, don't keep adding more questions to the same post.

Comment: It is T. Sorry. I gave the wrong name of generic type. Can you please answer the question. I  need the answer. :-)